# Issues with custom URLRewrite rules in 7.9

Tags: intershop

Currently I'm having some issues with custom URL rewrite rules within ISH `7.9`.

For some of our environments it works fine (like local and test), but on ACC and PROD it only seems to work from time to time after multiple deploys/restarts of the system.

We have created a custom cartridge that has a `deploy.gradle` file to exclude the files `urlrewriterules.xml`, `domainsplittings.xml` and `syndication-targets.properties` from the original cartridges. They get replaced by our custom files in the `share/system/config/cluster` folder. The static rules applied in the `urlrewriterules.xml` always work fine. However the rules that are coming from custom Java classes sometimes don't get well loaded by the `RewriteRuleFactoryImpl` returning back the below error:

`[2018-11-07 08:20:37.906 +0100] WARN  localhost ES1 appserver0 [ShipSupport-ebusiness-Site] [-] com.intershop.component.urlrewrite.internal.factory.RewriteRuleFactoryImpl [] [Storefront] [wJ5DCcg2CM5DCZPUUqdNu2D2fj8NZHaXjvP9qIZb] [yFAAAFvikjkOsqjA-0-00] "yFAAAFvikjkOsqjA-0-00" An implementation of rewrite rule type 'CustomCategory' does not exist.`

The part of code in the `urlrewriterules.xml` that will call this java class is the following:

```
<!-- Custom Category Rule /c/<NAME_OF_LOWEST_CATEGORY> -->
<rule type="CustomCategory" priority="1000" name="custom category rule">
    <configurations>
       <configuration id="pathPrefix">/catalog</configuration>
        <configuration id="partsCatalogID">4393</configuration>
   </configurations>
</rule>
```

We also have the classes well created in our own cartridge such as `CustomCategoryRewriteRule` that extends `BaseRewriteRule`. URL Rewrite is enabled for those channels and we always Invalidate the cache in the channels that have it enabled.

The extension for the CustomCategory (defined in the same cartridge) is defined as below:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<extensionpoint:ExtensionPointModel xmlns:extensionpoint="http://www.intershop.de/extensionpoint/2011" name="CustomCategoryRewriteRule"> 
  <extensionBindings type="java" extensionPoint="com.intershop.component.urlrewrite.capi.RewriteRule-RewriteRule.create" extension="com.package.CustomCategoryRewriteRule" priority="1"/>
</extensionpoint:ExtensionPointModel>
```

Also the app-extension.component is defined in the same cartridge as below:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<components xmlns="http://www.intershop.de/component/2010" scope="global">
    <fulfill requirement="selectedCartridge" value="cartridge_name" of="intershop.SLDSystem.Cartridges"/>
    <fulfill requirement="selectedCartridge" value="cartridge_name" of="intershop.EnterpriseBackoffice.Cartridges"/>
</components>
```

We followed this article to confirm on how to do it: https://support.intershop.com/kb/index.php/Display/B28069 We also have it working fine in another project, but using Intershop `7.8`.

Do you have any idea on what might be the cause?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Besides the implementation, you also need to create an extension file in `<cartridge>/staticfiles/cartridge/extensions`. This is the actual registration of the rewrite rule for the lookup mechanism. See the following example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<extensionpoint:ExtensionPointModel xmlns:extensionpoint="http://www.intershop.de/extensionpoint/2011" name="CustomRewriteRule.extension">
    <extensionBindings type="java" extensionPoint="com.intershop.component.urlrewrite.capi.RewriteRule-RewriteRule.create" extension="com.package.CustomCategoryRewriteRule " priority="1"/>
</extensionpoint:ExtensionPointModel>
```

Also the cartridge that contains these extensions needs to be registered at the application types via a component file in `<cartridge>/staticfiles/cartridge/components`. This is needed so that the extension is loaded correctly in the correct application context. See this example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<components xmlns="http://www.intershop.de/component/2010">
    <fulfill requirement="selectedCartridge" value="your_custom_cartridge" of="intershop.SLDSystem.Cartridges" /> 
    <fulfill requirement="selectedCartridge" value="your_custom_cartridge" of="intershop.B2CBackoffice.Cartridges" />
    <fulfill requirement="selectedCartridge" value="your_custom_cartridge" of="intershop.B2CResponsive.Cartridges" />
</components>
```

I'm not quite sure if you need to register it for all of these applications, but these are the ones we used in our last project. If you use different application types or have custom ones, make sure to add those accordingly.

Comment: We do have all these configurations in place, otherwise it would not work in any environment. The problem we have is that, for certain environments, it only works from 'time to time' after a certain amount of rebuilds/deploys.

Comment: It seems this is an issue with the implementation of the `RewriteRuleFactoryImpl`: This factory is registered as singleton and the rules are loaded lazily only once and then cached. However, for loading the rules only the current application at the time of the lookup is considered. If this is an application which does not contain the cartridge, then it may be missing and will never get loaded.

/edit: 
As a workaround, you may try to register the cartridge for more application types (especially the storefront ones) and see if the issue still persists.

Comment: I just managed to reproduce the issue locally by registering a cartridge (with some custom rewrite rules) for the applications `SLDSystem` and `EnterpriseBackoffice` only (just like in your example). After starting the application server, I first opened a storefront page (application type `B2CResponsive`). The rewrite rules don't get loaded in this case and the URLs will never be re-written. However, if I open the backoffice first after server start, then the rules will get loaded and everything is working fine.

Comment: Adding the storefront application types seems to have fixed our issue indeed. Thanks!

Comment: We tested the same but using the SMBResponsive cartridge instead. That small difference in your code and ours also caught my attention. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

We ended up solving it out by apply the SMBResponsive cartridge as well.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<components xmlns="http://www.intershop.de/component/2010" scope="global">
    <fulfill requirement="selectedCartridge" value="royalihc_sldsystem" of="intershop.SLDSystem.Cartridges"/>
    <fulfill requirement="selectedCartridge" value="royalihc_sldsystem" of="intershop.EnterpriseBackoffice.Cartridges"/>
    <fulfill requirement="selectedCartridge" value="royalihc_sldsystem" of="intershop.SMBResponsive.Cartridges" />
</components>
```

Thanks Andreas for all the help.